# Is there a way to prevent oversubscription using Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I am in a team of people organising an event. [image: There are concurrent workshops and applicants have to select online which one they'd like to attend.].

So in the picture, for the first session, each person only attends one of the strands and not both.

Is there a way of preventing oversubscription, such that if in the Google Form 50 people select Strand B (which is the max we can have for each strand) and submit the form, the option for Strand B disappears in the Form so that it can no longer be selected?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way to prevent subscription, actually there are several ways. Once the limit is reached the option should be removed

- manually
- by using a method that includes the use of script described by Martin Hawksey (see the reference).
- by using an addon like [Choice eliminator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/choice-eliminator/mnhoinjhhhafgieggnhjekliaodnkigj?utm_source=permalink) (mentioned in the reference).

## Reference

- [Dynamically remove Google Form options after they have been selected by someone or reach defined limits](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/11/dynamically-remove-google-form-options-after-they-have-been-selected-by-someone-or-reach-defined-limits/)

Answer (score -2):

Just look for the add-on: form limiter